# bash paste multiple columns into same file

Tags: bash, paste

I am running a command in a loop to produce a file with n number of columns. For the sake of the example, let's say 10 to make it simple. For example:

```
# Run the command to produce the data. Pipe the output to a temp file
${command here} > tmp1.txt

# We have a bit of superfluous information, so just pipe the output we need
tail -n +7 tmp1.txt | awk '{print $7}' > tmp2.txt
```

The above command would just produce a single file with 1 column of data.

The problem is, I want this all encased in a loop to run n number of times. Therefore, tmp3.txt (the output) should have n number of columns. When I tried to add the following command:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
  ${command here} > tmp1.txt
  tail -n +7 tmp1.txt | awk '{print $7}' > tmp2.txt
  if [[ ! -f tmp3.txt ]]
  then
    cp tmp2.txt tmp3.txt
  else
    paste -d' ' tmp2.txt tmp3.txt >> tmp3.txt
  fi
done
```

The file blows up and I run out of memory after even 3 or 4 iterations. How would I achieve what is desired? It would be cumbersome to write out 30-50 times and paste each file individually.

Comment: Probably because `tmp3.txt >> tmp3.txt`, tmp3.txt appearing on both sides of the redirection.

Comment: Never output to one of your inputs. "Don't cross the streams!"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
paste -d' ' tmp2.txt tmp3.txt > tmp4.txt  &&  mv tmp4.txt tmp3.txt
```

You should never read and write in same file.